# Split a Column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to split a column in SQL. There is an Address, then a series of spaces (which vary between row) and either a 4 or 5 character date (ex. 11/04 or 3/15) and then another large set of spaces.

I want to grab the dates but not have them get cut off. My big problem now is that the last digit of the zip code will enter into the date or we will cut off the first part of the date depending on which method we use

```
,CASE WHEN Addresses ='Missing' THEN 'Missing'  ELSE  RIGHT(replace(Addresses2,space(1),''),6) END AS EmploymentDate
,CASE WHEN Addresses ='Missing' THEN 'Missing'  ELSE  RIGHT(replace(Addresses2,space(1),''),7) END AS EmploymentDate2
```

[image: Visualization of the problem here]

Answer (score 2):

Trim spaces from right, then take the date, then trim spaces from left:

```
SELECT t.Addresses2,LTRIM(RIGHT(RTRIM(t.Addresses2),5)) AS [EmploymentDate]
FROM [YourTableName] t
;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `patindex()`.  Assuming there are at least three spaces before the date:

```
select trim(substring(address, patindex('%   [0-9]%', address) + 3, 5))
```